# Hide map fragment on change of tab

Tags: android, android-videoview, supportmapfragment

I used google maps v2 for showing map on 3rd tab.And used videoview for playing videos in app.When app navigates from map's tab to video's tab,map fragment gets overlap on videoview as shown

[image]

Please suggest any solution to hide map fragment on tab navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem but i fixed. put your map in a layout. and in map activity call mapLayout.removeAllViews(); in onPause() method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    mapLayout.removeAllViews();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could remove it programatically:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(mapFragment);
ft.commit();
```